# Updating table records using cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, cursors

I have the below assignments at work and wonder if anyone can help me out.
I need to use cursors in order to update records based on next records. Whenever the key is not equal to 8, i need to check all the records after it where key starts with 8 and update date2 with its max date

My data looks like this:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║     ID  date1      date2         key ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║     1   1/2/2014    5/2/2014      1  ║
║     1   5/2/2014    8/2/2014      8  ║
║     1   8/2/2014    9/2/2014      8  ║
║     1   11/2/2014   12/2/2014     1  ║   
║     1   12/2/2014   14/2/2014     8  ║ 
║     2   12/2/2014   14/2/2014     1  ║
║     2   14/2/2014   17/2/2014     8  ║
║     3   20/2/2014   23/2/2014     1  ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

After being updated, data will look like:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║     ID  date1      date2         key ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║     1   1/2/2014    9/2/2014      1  ║
║     1   5/2/2014    8/2/2014      8  ║
║     1   8/2/2014    9/2/2014      8  ║
║     1   11/2/2014   14/2/2014     1  ║   
║     1   12/2/2014   14/2/2014     8  ║ 
║     2   12/2/2014   17/2/2014     1  ║
║     2   14/2/2014   17/2/2014     8  ║
║     3   20/2/2014   23/2/2014     1  ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: How you are ordering the records? If I to say this record comes after this record on what basis I say that?

Comment: @kermit, ofcourse i am not asking you to do my work. I am just asking for advice because I never used SQL cursors before since they are not recommended. Anyway the idea of cursor usage came from my boss. The data are saved in an SQL table

Comment: @AsfakulIslam, I am ordering records based on ID and date1.

Comment: There will almost certainly be a better way than cursors then. I don't really understand your desired results though. Why is `5/2/2014` set to `9/2/2014` and not `14/2/2014`?

Comment: @MartinSmith: `check all the records after it where key starts with 8 and update date2 with its max date`

Comment: @MartinSmith The entries flagged as 1 in database are real entries. while the ones flagged as 8 are fictitious. As a company requirement they requested that for every real entry to check if it contains fictitious ones and update real entry - date 2 with the maximum fictitious date2.

Comment: If there was a row, say, `1, 14/2/2014, 17/2/2014, 8`, which would be after the last key=1 row in your example, would the `5/2/2014` date need to be updated with `17/2/2014`, or should that 17/2/2014 row be disregarded because it is preceded with another key=1 row?

Comment: @AndriyM okay if there was a row, 1, 14/2/2014, 17/2/2014, 8,                        after 1   12/2/2014   14/2/2014     1  .. .then the 14/2/2014 should be updated with 17/2/2014

Comment: And what is the relevance of the `ID` column?

Comment: @MartinSmith, ID refers to student ID. so basically i cant update date2 in case key 8 date 2 had a different ID from key 1 date 2. I have updated my main example. thanks for baring with me, this is the first time i use the forum

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency as the question says `max(date2)` but your earlier comment talks about ordering by `date1`?

Comment: @MartinSmith: They appear to be ranges, so the order of `date2` follows the order of `date1`.

Comment: Your edit makes some things clearer, but before the change it seemed there could be multiple key=1 rows per ID, and now you've changed it so there's just one. Can there actually be more than one key 1 per ID?

Comment: @AndriyM Only if all the ranges are the same length or at least they never overlap.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, that's another thing not clarified explicitly.

Comment: @AndriyM, there is always one record per ID & date 1

Comment: Sorry, I realise this all may have become a little tiresome but your last reply was a bit confusing. If the limitation is one key=1 row per ID & date1, then that allows more than one key=1 row per ID, correct? Or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @AndriyM  Here is the scenario. students pass by cafeteria multiple times. ID references to the student number, date 1 is the admission date and date 2 is the discharge 2. for billing purposes sometimes the cashier splits their visit to multiple entries(key 1 represents the real entry and 8 the fictitious). i need to check how much students are staying in the cafeteria (that is date2 - date 1).  In the case where a real entry has a fictitious entry then my calculation will be (max fictitious date 2 - real date 1) for every ID & date 1 record

Comment: So a key=1 row and the immediately following however many key=8 rows actually constitute a single date range that for certain reasons had to be split into several smaller ones. Key 1 gets the first portion, others go into key 8 rows. And now you need to restore the original date2 in the key 1 row. So far so good. Just one more (last?) question: using your scenario, could the same student have date1 of 1/2/2014 and corresponding real date2 of 9/2/2014 *and* have another date1=3/2/2014 and e.g. date2=10/2/2014? IOW, could different real intervals of date1..date2 intersect for the same student?

Comment: @AndriyM no intersection of dates for the same student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there was one key 1 row per ID and all existing key 8 rows with the same ID value were related to it, you could try this method:

```
WITH maxdates AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    maxdate2 = MAX(CASE [key] WHEN 8 THEN date2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
  FROM dbo.atable
)
UPDATE maxdates
SET date2 = maxdate2
WHERE [key] = 1
  AND maxdate2 IS NOT NULL
;
```

This is how it works. The `maxdates` common table expression uses a window MAX function to determine the maximum `date2` values per group (per ID in this case). If this was the original dataset:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  date1      date2      key ║
╠═══════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   1/2/2014   5/2/2014   1   ║
║ 1   5/2/2014   8/2/2014   8   ║
║ 1   8/2/2014   9/2/2014   8   ║
║ 2   12/2/2014  14/2/2014  1   ║
║ 2   14/2/2014  17/2/2014  8   ║
║ 3   20/2/2014  23/2/2014  1   ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╝
```

the CTE would turn it into the following:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  date1      date2      key  maxdate2  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   1/2/2014   5/2/2014   1    9/2/2014  ║
║ 1   5/2/2014   8/2/2014   8    9/2/2014  ║
║ 1   8/2/2014   9/2/2014   8    9/2/2014  ║
║ 2   12/2/2014  14/2/2014  1    17/2/2014 ║
║ 2   14/2/2014  17/2/2014  8    17/2/2014 ║
║ 3   20/2/2014  23/2/2014  1    NULL      ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

The UPDATE statement would first filter out rows that are not to be updated, i.e. those where `key` is 8 as well as the key 1 rows that have no associated key 8 rows (determining them by the absent `maxdate2`), resulting in this subset:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  date1      date2      key  maxdate2  ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   1/2/2014   5/2/2014   1    9/2/2014  ║
║ 2   12/2/2014  14/2/2014  1    17/2/2014 ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

and then update `date2` with `maxdate2`.

Now, this method could still be applicable even if multiple key 1 rows per ID were allowed. You would simply need to come up with another criterion to recognise subgroups of relevant rows within the same ID group. That is, you would first need to turn a dataset like this:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  date1      date2      key ║
╠═══════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   1/2/2014   5/2/2014   1   ║
║ 1   5/2/2014   8/2/2014   8   ║
║ 1   8/2/2014   9/2/2014   8   ║
║ 1   12/2/2014  14/2/2014  1   ║
║ 1   14/2/2014  17/2/2014  8   ║
║ 1   20/2/2014  23/2/2014  1   ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╝
```

into something like this:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ID  date1      date2      key  rangeID  ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1   1/2/2014   5/2/2014   1    1        ║
║ 1   5/2/2014   8/2/2014   8    1        ║
║ 1   8/2/2014   9/2/2014   8    1        ║
║ 1   12/2/2014  14/2/2014  1    2        ║
║ 1   14/2/2014  17/2/2014  8    2        ║
║ 1   20/2/2014  23/2/2014  1    3        ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

then apply the method.

One way to add such a criterion would be to use a conditional running count, as in this query:

```
WITH partitions AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    rangeID = COUNT(CASE [key] WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date1)
  FROM dbo.atable
),
maxdates AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    maxdate2 = MAX(CASE [key] WHEN 8 THEN date2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, rangeID)
  FROM partitions
)
UPDATE maxdates
SET date2 = maxdate2
WHERE [key] = 1
  AND maxdate2 IS NOT NULL
;
```

Basically, `COUNT() OVER (... ORDER BY ...)` is a running count and the CASE expression makes it conditional: the count only increases on key 1 rows and remains the same on the others. The `partitions` CTE obtains independent running count for every ID partition. As a result, you get rangeID values as illustrated previously.

The `maxdates` CTE reads the result of `partitions` and uses the rangeID values as the additional criterion I was talking about. The rest of the second query follows the first query's logic.

A live demonstration of this method can be found [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0446a/1).

Related manual pages that might be helpful:

- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)
- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Comment: thank you a lot for the above update. however the above failed in the below case:                                                              ║     1   1/2/2014    5/2/2014      1  ║
║     1   5/2/2014    8/2/2014      8  ║
║     1   8/2/2014    9/2/2014      8  ║
║     1   11/2/2014   12/2/2014     1  ║   
║     1   12/2/2014   14/2/2014     8  ║

Comment: The SQL Fiddle demo contains this case and I thought I'd covered it correctly. Could you please elaborate on the incorrect bit and explain what the expected result is?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a `CURSOR`.

Are you trying to do the following?

(NB - I've arranged the dates as dd/mm/yyyy, this is how it is done on other planets)

```
DECLARE @MyData TABLE (ID INT, date1 DATE, date2 DATE, [key] INT)
INSERT INTO @MyData (ID, date1, date2, [key])
    SELECT 1, '2/1/2014',    '2/5/2014',  1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '2/5/2014',    '2/8/2014',  8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '2/8/2014',    '2/9/2014',  8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2/12/2014',   '2/14/2014', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '2/14/2014',   '2/17/2014', 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '2/20/2014',   '2/23/2014', 1

UPDATE MD
SET MD.date2 = DT.MaxDate2
FROM @MyData    MD
JOIN 
(
    SELECT   ID
            ,MaxDate2   = MAX(Date2)
    FROM @MyData
    WHERE [key] = 8
    GROUP BY ID
)           DT  ON DT.ID = MD.ID
WHERE MD.[key] != 8

SELECT *
FROM @MyData
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really hope i can fix this thing without a cursor cz the data is huge and cursors will kill the performance. 
however just a small inquiry, in case data has another record like this: SELECT 1, '2/11/2014',    '2/12/2014',  1..                                                                                               SELECT 1, '12/11/2014',    '2/15/2014',  8..               wouldn't the above fail